# Fix WSL - cannot access '/mnt/c': Input/output error

Tags: linux, windows, crash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I hit a problem with my WSL Ubuntu system, where I can't `ls` the `C:\` drive from within my WSL Ubuntu Linux system...

```shell
mpenning@wsl$ ls /mnt/c
ls: cannot access '/mnt/c': Input/output error
mpenning@wsl$
```

How do I fix this so I can see the contents of `C:\` from inside my WSL Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377).

It happens if the `wsl.exe` processes [crashes](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377#issuecomment-530537540).

In short, to fix this just exit out of your WSL Linux shell and run:

```
C:\Users\mike.pennington> wsl --shutdown
C:\Users\mike.pennington>
```

Now you can go back to your WSL instance and `ls /mnt/c` works just fine.

You can also unmount and re-mount `C:\` in WSL without exiting Linux, but I think it's cleaner to exit and shutdown `wsl.exe` if you can.